# Factors of a polynomial in several variables

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Fix an embedding of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ into $\mathbb{C}$.
Suppose you have a polynomial in several variables, with algebraic coefficients: $P\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$.  Also suppose we find some factorization $P=QR$ for some $Q, R\in \mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$ (with, a priori, just complex coefficients).

It seems intuitively clear to me that $Q$ and $R$ would need to have algebraic coefficients as well.  (Well, almost -- we might need to do some scaling first.  Let's say we pick some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^\times$ such that $\alpha Q$ has at least one nonzero, algebraic coefficient.  Then replace $Q$ and $R$ with $\alpha Q$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha} R$.)  Can anyone remind me how you would go about proving this?

(I'm sure this has nothing to do with the particulars of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, really -- we could probably replace them with any pair of nested, algebraically closed fields.)